# Is $x^3+x=y^3+2y-1$ a function? Why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

This equation was given:
$$x^3+2x=y^3+2y-1$$
Now please tell me some hints about how I can check if
$$x_1=x_2$$
Then $$y_1=y_2$$
And which differences of squares are needed to rewrite $y$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: I don't understand $x_1=x_2$ here. What do you want to ask? If $2=2$ then what?

Comment: Oh i m blind! Sorry .edited thnks

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. What do you want to know, if you can express $y$ in terms of $x$ as a function ?

Comment: Further to @DietrichBurde's question, you have $+x$ in the question but $+2x$ in the body.

Comment: Check if we have 2 equal x  , then y woudl be equal for them

Comment: I want to write y in terms of x too. Yeah you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, you want to know if, given
\begin{cases}
y_1^3+2y_1-1=x^3+x \\[4px]
y_2^3+2y_2-1=x^3+x
\end{cases}
you can conclude that $y_1=y_2$.

The two equations imply
$$
y_1^3-y_2^3+2y_1-2y_2=0
$$
that factors as
$$
(y_1-y_2)(y_1^2+y_1y_2+y_2^2+2)=0
$$
Can you show that the second factor is positive for any $y_1$ and $y_2$?

Answer (score 0):

Both sides are strictly increasing cubic functions of their variable - for example, you can show this with calculus - so they each never take the same value twice. This implies $x$ is a function of $y$ and vice versa. But if you really want a formula for the result in either direction, I think you'll need to solve (e.g. by [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method) - think of it as cubics' equivalent of the quadratic formula.), and the result won't be neat.

Comment: I want to write y in terms of x. How do I do that?

Comment: @user602338 It's a way for solving a cubic equation. It's like the quadratic formula for cubic equations.

Comment: @user602338 You can do that using Cardano's method https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/

Comment: @user602338 You talk about completing the square in your question... are you sure it wasn't supposed to be squared instead of cubed?

Comment: @Ovi Sorry but I really don't know how! Please help me with that!

Comment: @Ovi Would you please clearly instruct me how to write y in terms of x?????

Comment: I'd be happy to improve this answer to address the downvote, if it's explained.